# Proof Using Model Universe

Tags: logic, proof, predicate-logic

Suppose I am trying to prove the following argument

(∀x)(Cx → Dx), (∀x)(Ex → ~Dx), /∴ (∀x)(Ex → ~Cx)

Now, let's also assume that I don't know if this argument is valid or not. Because of this, I try to check for invalidity using the model universe method (even though it would be easy enough to construct a direct proof).

I start by restricting the domain to D = {a}, and I check the following argument for a situation where I have true premises and a false conclusion.

Ca → Da, Ea → ~Da, /∴ Ea → ~Ca

Obviously, I can't find a counter-example, so I continue to expand the domain to D = {a, b}, D = {a, b, c}, etc.

Now, there is a theorem for the model universe method that states, "If n is the number of predicate variables in an argument, 2^n is the upper bound of elements you can test in a domain before you can determine that the argument is valid."

If I test the above argument using the model universe method to the point that my domain includes 8 (2^n) elements, have I just constructed a formal proof? Would I be able to use the model universe method as a means to formally prove an argument?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

This problem was not taken from a book, but we're going to define a formal proof as "a finite sequence of well-formed formulas, each of which is an axiom, an assumption, or follows from the preceding sentences in the sequence by a rule of inference." And yes, this is in the context of monadic predicate calculus.

Comment: Are you following some text or other source? The answer may depend on what their definition of "formal proof" is.

Comment: @Conifold Thanks for your interest in the question. I just edited it for clarification.

Comment: So are you *only* allowed to use axioms and rules of inference of monadic predicate calculus in a "formal proof"? Because setting up models and proving the completeness theorem you mentioned requires other means, such as set theory and maybe induction. Using them will not make a "formal proof in monadic predicate calculus".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes-ish: it takes some work to formalize it, but it can be done.

Specifically, the proof of the relevant model checking theorem gives a general method for proving, for an appropriate sentence **p**, a sentence of the form "If **q**_i implies **p** for each i < n, then **p** is true" where n is the appropriate bound and {**q_i**: i < n} are sentences characterizing each of the relevant finite isomorphism types. Each individual model check in turn is formalized as a proof of "**q**_i implies **p**." Putting this together gives a formal proof of **p**.

However, keep in mind that that theorem only holds when our language consists entirely of unary relation *(or predicate, if you prefer)* symbols. Since that's really a very rare situation, I'd say it's a good idea to avoid it when possible (especially in a case like this where it's much harder than the proof not using the theorem).

Comment: I am not sure what the intended meaning of a "formal proof" is in the OP. Using a model argument, even together with a proof of the completeness (meta)theorem, is not really a "formal proof" in the object theory (monadic predicate calculus, I presume).

Comment: @Conifold It is, though: for each of the finitely many isomorphism types we can find a sentence $\psi$ characterizing it up to isomorphism (every finite structure in a finite language has such a sentence); the model checking then amounts to proving that each such $\psi$ implies the theorem we want, together with the proof of the model checking theorem above. The casework is entirely formalizable inside the object theory.

Comment: This uses metatheoretic means beyond the ones of the theory itself. I am just not sure what his textbook allows as "formal proofs". If it interprets "formal proof" as syntactic, semantic means are off-limits.  But if it just means "rigorous" in some loose sense, they would be ok.

Comment: @Conifold See my edit.

Comment: @Conifold No it doesn't: the formalized version of that instance of the model checking theorem does exactly this. It really is straightforwardly formalizable.

Comment: I agree that it is formalizable, and that it can be converted into a formal proof in the narrow sense. But it isn't itself a formal proof in monadic predicate calculus. For one, the latter does not even have expressive means to talk about sets, i.e. models.

Comment: @Conifold That's fair - I've added a bit to say what needs to go into the formalization.

Comment: Maybe a preamble on the dependence of "formal proof" on a formal system it is given in might also help, I think the OP is somewhat inexperienced.

Comment: @Conifold Not inexperienced (though I might be in more general philosophy), I think this question just got a bit out of hand as I was asking something much simpler than was interpreted. Basically, could I hand a mathematician a "proof" using the model universe method and have him not laugh at me and go, "this isn't a proof!"

Comment: @N.Bar Ah - in *that* sense, it's certainly a proof. But it's important to distinguish between the informal notion of "rigorous proof" and actual *formal proofs*.

Comment: @Conifold I think you're right (regardless of the OP, certainly for other readers) - I don't have time to do that right now, but within the next couple hours I'll improve this.